# SQLite difference between dates as a percentage of group

Tags: sql, sqlite, date

I have the following table:

```
group -       date1                   - date2 
A     -  2014- 04-04 09:20:04.903     - 2015-05-04 09:20:04.903
A     -  2015- 04-04 09:20:04.903     - 2015-03-04 09:20:04.903
B     -  2016- 04-04 09:20:04.903     - None
B     -  2016- 07-04 09:20:04.903     - 2015-07-04 09:20:04.903
```

How can I count the ratio of number of times that the dates differ by a year or less to the total entries for each group? date2 can be none but date1 is not. For example, both group A and B would be 50%, because one entry differs by less than a year, and so the ratio is 1/2.

This is because, the first entry differs by more than a year, the second entry by less, the 3rd entry is missing date2 (so counts as more than a year) and the fourth is exactly a year. So the ratio for both groups is 50%.

Comment: I don't understand your ratios/logic.  The B group has only a single record, so its ratio must be either 0 or 1.

Comment: Edited question to make it more clear.

Comment: This could be tricky due to leap years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use conditional aggregation here over the groups, checking if the number of days between timestamps is within one year.  I make two assumptions in the query below.  One is that if one (or both) dates be missing, I count that record as a match.  The other is that I use 365 days to represent a year.  This is technically incorrect; a leap year has an extra day (and sometimes an extra second).

```
SELECT
    "group",
    100.0 *
    SUM(CASE WHEN COALESCE(ABS(julianday(date1) - julianday(date2)), 0) <= 365 
             THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(*) AS ratio
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY "group"
```

Comment: I was thinking of ensuring that `date1` <= `date2` and then using `CASE WHEN datetime(date2) <= datetime(date1, '+1 year') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`, but yeah, this.

Comment: @LordThompson Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

A slight variation on @Tim's answer:

Your sample table has cases where date1 < date2 and where date1 > date2 so let's start with a query to ensure that date1 <= date2:

```sql
SELECT "group", date1, date2
FROM table1
WHERE date1 <= date2 OR date2 IS NULL
UNION ALL 
SELECT "group", date2, date1
FROM table1
WHERE date1 > date2
```

```
group |date1                   |date2                   |
------|------------------------|------------------------|
A     |2014-04-04 09:20:04.903 |2015-05-04 09:20:04.903 |
B     |2016-04-04 09:20:04.903 |                        |
A     |2015-03-04 09:20:04.903 |2015-04-04 09:20:04.903 |
B     |2015-07-04 09:20:04.903 |2016-07-04 09:20:04.903 |
```

Now we can count the rows based on their condition

```sql
SELECT 
    "group", 
    100.0 * SUM(CASE WHEN datetime(date2) <= datetime(date1, '+1 year') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(*) AS percent_year_or_less
FROM
    (
        SELECT "group", date1, date2
        FROM table1
        WHERE date1 <= date2 OR date2 IS NULL
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT "group", date2, date1
        FROM table1
        WHERE date1 > date2
    )
GROUP BY "group"
```

```
group |percent_year_or_less |
------|---------------------|
A     |50.0                 |
B     |50.0                 |
```

Comment: Actually what I think is better about your answer is your use of the `datetime` function with `+1 year` to get around the issue of leap years.